# How to detect Image URL and do the validatation using Jquery OR MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, model-view-controller

I want to detect the image URL of a set of images, and if any of the image URL is "cameraNotFound.jpg" the user should get the error message and should not be able to click to the "Proceed" button.

Below is my code where its checking initially if the image is available in datatbase it shows the image but if its not available then it shows the "cameraNotFound.jpg" image.

Please see the code  below:

```
<div id="list">



    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Cameras.Count; i++)
    {
        CameraDto camera = Model.Cameras[i];
        <div>
            <p>

                @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(camera.Base64Image))
                {
                    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" id="pickheadImageLightBox" title="@camera.Name : @camera.SerialNumber" href="/Content/Images/graphics/cameraNotFound.jpg">
                        <img alt="@i" id="pickheadImage" src="/Content/Images/graphics/cameraNotFound.jpg" width="200" height="150" />
                    </a>
                }
                else
                {  
                    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" id="pickheadImageLightBox" title="@camera.Name : @camera.SerialNumber" href="@("data:image/jpg;base64," + camera.Base64Image)">
                        <img alt="@i" id="pickheadImage" src="@("data:image/jpg;base64," + camera.Base64Image)" width="200" height="150" />
                    </a>
                }
            </p>
            <p>
                <strong>@camera.Name:</strong><br />
                <span id="pickheadImageDetails">@camera.SerialNumber</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    }
</div>
<div class="clearall"></div>
<p class="redtext">Camera not found, please detect the cameras again!</p>
<div role="button" class="marginTop50 marginBottom">
    <input type="button" id="getCameraSerialNumbers" value="Detect Cameras" class="active" />
    <input type="button" id="confirmCameraSerialNumbers" value="Confirm & Proceed" disabled="disabled" class="disabled marginLeft50" />
</div>
```

I tried to use the same `@IF` statement for the  containing "error message and buttons" also.

```
@if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(camera.Base64Image))
{
    <p class="redtext">Camera not found, please detect the cameras agarn!</p>
    <div role="button" class="marginTop50 marginBottom">
        <input type="button" id="getCameraSerialNumbers" value="Detect Cameras" class="active" />
        <input type="button" id="confirmCameraSerialNumbers" value="Confirm & Proceed" disabled="disabled" class="disabled marginLeft50" />
    </div>
} else
{ <div role="button" class="marginTop50 marginBottom">
        <input type="button" id="getCameraSerialNumbers" value="Detect Cameras" class="active" />
        <input type="button" id="confirmCameraSerialNumbers" value="Confirm & Proceed" class="active marginLeft50" />
    </div>
}
```

But its not working, it is not able to refer to the "camera" variable.

Let me know if you need any other information.

Please suggest.

Comment: $("img[src$='cameraNotFound.jpg']").show()

Comment: what this will do? I am not sure how to use this?

Comment: maybe if($("img[src$='cameraNotFound.jpg']").length){ $("#confirmCameraSerialNumbers")[0].disabled=true;}

Comment: Can you provide the full page that is not working please?

Comment: @dandavis: Thanks for the suggestion.. it worked for me.. I changed the code a little. but used the logic u provided and its wooking cool.. I'll be sharing my working code too.. Thanks a ton!